# MSBuild: Capture command line properties in preprocessed file

Tags: properties, import, msbuild, preprocessor

Using MSBuild 4.0 (framework version v4.0.30319), I pass properties to MSBuild when calling a project file thus:

```
MSBuild Build.csproj /p:Property1=Value1
```

Is it possible to use the /pp (preprocess file) option to capture this in the generated file?

The reason I ask is that we have around 20 properties already set within an imported project file ... out of which we will normally override less than 10. The first time the Build project is run, the properties to override are passed via command line (by a batch file). The properties will (naturally) not have the modified values if the project is launched in the IDE. I tried placing them in an msbuild.rsp file adjacent to the project, and those do come into effect when MSBuild is invoked. But I want them to persist in an imported project file such that the IDE also knows the updated values. The imported file is dispensable and therefore I was trying to have the values persist inside it.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.